# how to reformat date type from MongoDB to Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

My question is simple how can I pipe type date ?? meanes if the date in MongoDB looks like this :
`2021-01-31T23:00:00.000+00:00`
and in my case I want it to take this format `2021-01-31` no more
please how can I do it I'm using MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express js, Angular, Node js)
I want to do it without changing it into a string and get a substring is that possible?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular, You need to use angular datePipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

HTML side:

```
{{ yourDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

If you want to convert it typescript side, you need to provide DatePipe in your appModule :

```
@NgModule({
....
    providers:[DatePipe]
....
})
```

Then you can use it as service in your component:

```
constructor(datePipe: DatePipe) {}
...
function() {
  const date = this.datePipe.transform(yourDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
}
```

Comment: thank you, that's means a lot to me